Custom Svelte RadioButton component appearence
I'm creating a radio button component but I have some issue with bind:group.
when I'm selecting a button, both graphic updates to the checked state.
I think it has to do with the checked variable, If I use the default appearence the buttons are selected one at time.
+Page.svelte
<RadioButton name="database" value="db1" bind:checked={radioValue}/>

<RadioButton name="database" value="db2" bind:checked={radioValue}/>

RadioButton.svelte
<script>
  import { toKebabCase } from "$lib/utils.js";
  import Icon from "$lib/components/Icon.svelte";

  export let checked;
  export let classNames = "";

  export let name = '';
  export let value = '';
</script>

<label for={toKebabCase(value)} class="relative flex flex-row items-center {classNames}">
  <input type="radio" id="{toKebabCase(value)}" name={name} value="{value}" class="flex shrink-0 h-5 w-5 mr-2 appearance-none" bind:group={checked} />

  <span class="absolute cursor-pointer">
    {#if checked}
      <Icon type="radioButtonChecked" classNames="h-6 w-6 fill-gs-teal" />
    {:else}
      <Icon type="radioButton" classNames="h-6 w-6 fill-white" />
    {/if}
  </span>

  <slot />

</label>

REPL: https://www.sveltelab.dev/ag6fd94upq3a0zf

This will not work, as the docs state:

bind:group only works if the inputs are in the same Svelte component.

You will have to work with checked or events directly.
It is also possible to introduce a wrapper component that coordinates the descendant radio button components via a shared context (see e.g. the RadioButtonGroup in the Svelte Carbon components for reference - the wrapper does not necesarily have to do anything in terms of layout, it can just contain a single <slot>).
